# defining "half" of a quadratic form over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Given a vector space, $V$, over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, I can sometimes construct a function $P:V \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ with the following property:

$$ P(x+y) = P(x) + P(y) + B(x,y) , \;\;\; \forall \;x,y \in V$$

where $B$ is a bilinear form, which is necessarily even.  For example, for $V={\mathbb{Z}_2}^2$, $P$ sends every non-zero vector to $1$, and then $B$ is the unique even form on $V$.  Note $P$ is behaving like half of a quadratic form, but of course one can't literally define this over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Is there a more general way to characterize such a $P$?

Comment: Are you also given $B$? Aside from that, this sounds like a chain complex question: $V^* \rightarrow Sym^2(V^*) \rightarrow ...$, and the cohomology at $Sym^2(V^*)$ should be key to answering your question.

Comment: Your function $P$ is a quadratic form on a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, as defined e.g.  in https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~roquette/arf.pdf .

Comment: one might think of $B$ as symplectic, if it helps

Comment: one might think of $B$ as symplectic, if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I agree that this is just a quadratic form, not "half" of one, as I had thought.  I was confused because in characteristic not equal to two, one can always associate a quadratic form with a symmetric bilinear form, but here there is no such correspondence.  I'm curious to what extent $P$ is determined by $B$.